# Building JSON from SQLite Data in jQuery/javascript

Tags: jquery, json, sqlite

I'm currently working on a prototype mobile app that should support pulling data from a server to the device, storing that data in an SQLite DB on the device, allow the user to manipulate the data, then push the data from the SQLite DB back up to the server. So far, everything is working great until the last part. I'm having trouble getting information back out of the SQLite tables and into a JSON object to push back up to the server.

My basic issue at this point is figuring out how to build a JSON object from the data in SQLite given that all db transactions in javascript are asynchronous from my understanding.

I've got a jsFiddle with some example code:
http://jsfiddle.net/uu29g/

My hope is to push something up to the server that looks like this:

```
[{"order_num": "2001", "custnum": "ABC123", "custname": "Demo Customer", "status": "S", "id": 1, "lineitems": [{"id": 1, "line_num": "1", "part_num": "WSC599", "part_desc": 'Widget A', "qty": "2.0", "price": "15.00"}, {"id": 2, "line_num": "2", "part_num": "FFC898B", "part_desc": 'Dongle B', "qty": "1.0", "price": "32.98"},
{"id": 3, "line_num": "3", "part_num": "RQFG", "part_desc": 'Dooflatchie', "qty": "5.0", "price": "200"}]},{"order_num": "2002", "custnum": "ZXY987", "custname": "Another Customer", "status": "S", "id": 2, "lineitems": [{"id": 1, "line_num": "1", "part_num": "GHJH11", "part_desc": 'Lightsaber - Green', "qty": "1.0", "price": "1500.00"}, 
{"id": 2, "line_num": "2", "part_num": "C3P0", "part_desc": 'Protocol Droid', "qty": "1.0", "price": "9811.04"}]}]
```

Given the database in the jsFiddle example, what would be the best way to generate an object like the above from the SQLite data? **Edit**: Specifically, how do I build that object from three async queries? My current train of thought is to get a list of order numbers from the order_header table (in my jsFiddle example), loop over those order numbers and pull the order_header info and order_detail/line item info from the tables for each order and push that into an object, then push each order object into a final array/object. Where I'm struggling is with how to get the header and detail data from SQLite when the sql queries are asynchronous. (And I might be going about this totally wrong).

*FYI: I'm still learning about Deferred objects in jQuery. The app I'm working on is built using jQuery Mobile, and meant to work on iOS/Android and will be turned into a native app via phoneGap

Answer (score 1):

YOu can use [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify). To transform any JavaScript object into a string.

Also if you set a JavaScript object in the [jQUery ajax request](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), it is transmitted as a String.

Comment: Thank you for your comment Stefan, but I wasn't clear enough in my question. I've updated it to hopefully be more clear.

Comment: ok sorry, I thought this would be to easy. I will try a solution before I post it. I think it's best to use .promise() (http://api.jquery.com/promise/ ), which can be used for other things than animation too. However first I think I have to understand the HTML5 datastore better

Answer (score 0):

OK, I finally figured this out thanks to a few different sources around the web and a lot of trial and error.
[jsFiddle example:](http://jsfiddle.net/BYzLx/5/)

Basically what I wound up doing is the following:

1. Run a deferred SQL transaction to get the orders I need to pull.
2. Pipe the results of the deferred transaction into an anonymous function.
3. Loop over the results in the anonymous function and populate an array of deferred functions, passing in the order numbers I need to pull data on.
4. Execute a $.when.apply(null, deferreds) function on the deferred array of deferred functions.
5. Inside of the deferred function each order calls in the deferred array, I execute all of the SQL (via deferred functions) as part of s $.when(...).done() function, and inside the done callback, run a function to handle the results from all the deferred queries, and push my generated order objects into a global array.

Now I just need to get my deferred function in step 5 to return a promise so I can do something with the global array when everybody is done.

I'm sure this could be written better, and I'm sure there are potential pitfalls with my logic, but hopefully this will set other people on the right track if they have a similar issue.

Not the cleanest code in the world by any means, but it works (see jsFiddle for SQL statements, db init, etc).

```
var ordersArr = [];

/*
Thanks to Josh Ross's answer here for how to do SQL transactions that return a deferred object
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058679/wrapping-websql-executesql-calls-in-a-jquery-deferred-promise
*/
function successWrapper(d) {
//console.log(d);
return (function (tx, data) {
    d.resolve(data)

})
};

function failureWrapper(d) {
console.log("Sql failed");
return (function (tx, error) {
    d.reject(error)
})
};  



function getMyOrdersSQL() {
return $.Deferred(function (d) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(getSyncableOrdersStatement, [], 
                    successWrapper(d), failureWrapper(d));
                });
    });
}

function getHeaderDataSQL(ordernum) {
return $.Deferred(function (d) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(getOrdHeaderSingleStatement, [ordernum], 
                    successWrapper(d), failureWrapper(d));
                });
    });
}


function getDetailDataSQL(ordernum) {
return $.Deferred(function (d) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(getOrderDetStatement, [ordernum], 
                    successWrapper(d), failureWrapper(d));
                });
    });
}

function getNoteDataSQL(ordernum) {
return $.Deferred(function (d) {
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
                    tx.executeSql(getDriverNoteStatment, [ordernum], 
                    successWrapper(d), failureWrapper(d));
                });
    });
}


function getOrders() {

$.when(getMyOrdersSQL()).pipe(function(dta) {
    var deferreds = [];
    //build an array of deferred SQL transactions
    //each deferred transaction should populate an order object, then push it into the final ordersArr array
    if (dta.rows.length > 0) {
        for (var i=0; i<dta.rows.length; i++) {
            //console.log(dta.rows.item(i).order_num);
            deferreds.push(getOrdStuff(dta.rows.item(i).order_num)); //push in a function for each order in the getMyOrdersSQL resultset
        }
        $.when.apply(null, deferreds); //run all the deferred functions

    }else {
        console.log(dta.rows);  
        alert("No records found!");
    }
}).done(function() {

}).fail(function() {
    alert("Failed!");
});
}

function getOrdStuff(ordernum) {
console.log(ordernum);
return $.Deferred(function(d) {
    var orderObj = new Object(); //object to hold the order info
    //getDriverNoteStatment
    //getOrdeDetSingle
    //getOrdHeaderSingleStatement

    $.when(getHeaderDataSQL(ordernum), getDetailDataSQL(ordernum), getNoteDataSQL(ordernum)).done(
    function(dta1, dta2, dta3) {
        //dta1 is the deferred promise/result from the getHeaderDataSQL function
        //dta2 is the deferred promise/result from the getDetailDataSQL function
        //dta3 is the deferred promise/result from the getNoteDataSQL function                      
        var orderHeader = dta1.rows.item(0); 

        var orderNotes = dta3.rows.item(0);

        orderObj.order_num = orderHeader.order_num;
        orderObj.status = orderHeader.status;
        orderObj.shipto_num = orderHeader.shipto_num;
        orderObj.po_num = orderHeader.po_num;
        orderObj.billto_num = orderHeader.billto_num;


        var onObj = new Object(); //order notes object
        orderObj.notes = orderNotes.notes;
        orderObj.notes_dtstamp = orderNotes.dtstamp;

        var odArr = []; //order detail array to hold order line items objects

        for (var k = 0; k<dta2.rows.length; k++) { //loop over line item results
            console.log(dta1.rows.item(0).order_num+' has '+dta2.rows.length+' line items');
            var odObj = new Object();
            var orderDetails = dta2.rows.item(k);
            odObj.line_num = orderDetails.line_num;
            odObj.part_num = orderDetails.part_num;
            odObj.qty = orderDetails.qty;
            odObj.part_desc = orderDetails.part_desc;
            odArr.push(odObj); //push each line item object into the detail array

        }           

        orderObj.lineitems = odArr;
        ordersArr.push(orderObj);
        console.log("got stuff");
        console.log(ordersArr);
        return function(d) {
            d.resolve();    //return the promise
        }

    }).fail(function(etx, err) {
         d.reject(err, etx) //return the error if any transaction failed
    });


});


}
```